# Doubt on Binomial Series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Sorry to ask this simple question, but I am finding it hard to get a convincing answer

As we all know, binomial series is defined as 
$$(1 + x)^k = 1 + \frac{k}{1!}x + \frac{k(k-1)}{2!} x^2 + \dots,$$
where $k$ is a real number and $-1 < x < 1$.

Why the restriction $-1 < x < 1$? Even without this restriction, the series works fine, right? Why this restriction in every definition I see?

Comment: What exactly does "where $k$ is a real number and -1" mean?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by works fine. Let $x=-2$ and $k=-1$. If we take the series seriously we get $-1=1+2+2^2+2^3+2^4+\cdots$.

Comment: Thanks André Nicolas. I got my mistake. As nrpeterson pointed out, so when k is negative, the restriction is needed as I understand

Comment: The general statement is: either $k$ is a nonnegative integer, or $|x|<1$.  This holds for all complex (not just real) $x$.

Comment: But  vadim123, then what if k is a positive fraction, say 1/2 and x > 1, then also this may go wrong right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction $-1<x<1$ is only necessary for binomials of the form $(1+x)^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$. In this case, rather than a finite sum, you need an infinite number of terms of the series - and it turns out that the series has radius of convergence 1.

Comment: Thanks. So when α is a natural number, this restriction is not needed right?

Comment: Right.  Because when $\alpha$ is a natural number, we have that the coefficient by $x^n$ for $n>\alpha$ is $\binom{\alpha}{n}=0$, so that the sum is actually a polynomial with finitely many summands. The difference is that $\binom{\alpha}{n}\neq 0$ for $n>\alpha$ if $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$.